# how can i import a method to all my projects(like standard)?

Tags: java, class

I have here a simple password method that I want to trigger in specific places in all different console applications that I already made. I was aiming to packages but haven't knowledge about that.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Password {
    public void Password(){

        System.out.println("Enter password:");

        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

        boolean correct = false;

        do{
            String psw = scn.nextLine();
            if(psw.equals("my0opinion0of0a0master0password193847582C")){
                System.out.println("welcome");
                System.out.println("");
                correct = true;
            }else{
                System.out.println("Retry:");
            }           
        }while(!correct);
    }
}
```

and no; thats not my real password :P

Comment: You should try to build a jar and include it into your other applications. Furthermore, you should use maven to resolve the dependencies of your jar easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it a static method:

```
public class Password {
    public static void checkPassword(){
```

Then wherever you need it, use

```
Password.checkPassword()
```

or put in the top of your class:

```
import static Password.checkPassword;
```

and then you only need to use the method name

```
 checkPassword();
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an IDE like Eclipse ,NetBeans or Intellij Idea? 
If not, I would suggest you do, because it is very easy to work with packages, and packages really seem like the ideal solution here. 
So, I would put the Password class inside a package, and alter the password() method to be *static*. Then I would use the said method to any application by importing the Password class, and doing:

`Password.password();`

Comment: i'm running newest version on eclipse

Comment: And when you announce the class. Isn't the password already triggerd?
many thanks btw.

Comment: You mean the password() method to be triggered/called?  No, it is called as soon as the `Password.password()` line is executed. So is should be fine for reusability.

Comment: @MacLotsen Also, to avoid confusion, I would rename the method to something like `public static void checkPassword()`. Because its current name indicates that it's a constructor, but it's not.